# How to send value of textBox to string variable?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

How to send value of textBox to string variable?

I have View with html:

```
<body>
<div id="CalculatorSpace">
    <form name="Calc">
        <input type="text" name="textBox" id="textBox" value=""/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="btnSeven" id="btnSeven" value="7" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnEight" value="8" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnNine" value="9" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="DEL" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnClear" value="CLR" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnFour" value="4" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnFive" value="5" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnSix" value="6" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnMultiply" value="*" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnDivide" value="/" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnOne" value="1" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnTwo" value="2" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnThree" value="3" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnPlus" value="+" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnMinus" value="-" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnZero" value="0" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnDot" value="." /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnEqual" value="=" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnLBracket" value="(" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnRBracket" value=")" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('btnSeven').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnSeven').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnEight').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnEight').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnNine').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnNine').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnDelete').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnDelete').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnClear').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnClear').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnFour').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnFour').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnFive').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnFive').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnSix').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnSix').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnMultiply').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnMultiply').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnDivide').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnDivide').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnOne').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnOne').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnTwo').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnTwo').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnThree').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnThree').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnPlus').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnPlus').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnMinus').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnMinus').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnZero').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnZero').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnDot').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnDot').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnEqual').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnEqual').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnLBracket').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnLBracket').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnRBracket').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnRBracket').value;
                });
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

And I have Controller:

```
public class CalculatorController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Calculator/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    //GET: /Calculator/Calculate
    public ActionResult Calculate()
    {
        string expression;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now what I want is to send value of textBox to string expression, pars the expression like "5+5" and send value result to the textBox. Everything must be done by one clicking on button btnEqual. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That code runs on the server, not the client. To access the textbox at the server you must first define it as accessible on the server:

```
<input runat="server" type="text" name="textBox" id="textBox" value=""/>
```

Then you get the text imput by accessing the Text attribute:

```
string expression = textBox.Text;
```

Although this will require a postback, nowdays stuff like this is usually done in javascript.

Note: untested code, this might only work on the page load.

Comment: I get the error: The name 'textBox' does not exist in the current context in my Controller.

Comment: There is no page load in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

This will provide you the basic idea of sending the data to controller. If you want to get the value of the TextBox in the controller, then you can send the model to the controller on submit.

First Create the form in the View:

```
 @model MVCApp.Models.ModelClassName
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Calculator",
                        FormMethod.Post))
    {
    //codeing textboxes etc

    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="btnSubmit" />
    }
```

Now create a Action method in controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActionName(ModelClassName model)
    {
      //model is now containg all the values of controls present in the view
        return View();
    }
```

Note: This is the normal procedure by which you can send your data back to controller.

**You can also do the same by performing all the operation in the calculator at the client side using jquery and displaying the result at the same time. This pattern will prevent the hit on the server and your application will execute fast.**